# Flash loader CRC?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, crc

In a Flash/AIR app, if I download something using the URLLoader and the loader dispatches Event.COMPLETE - is the downloaded data guaranteed to be complete and correct?

If not, what's the best way to ensure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

URLLoader does a a HTTP request, which is implemented on top of TCP, which has a 16 bit Fletcher-style checksum.  Data arriving over TCP won't have errors due to TCP, which will request retransmits when there are checksum errors.  There are also very often checksums or other error detection at lower layers in the transmission.

When you get an `Event.COMPLETE` the data is ready to be used.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. I just made a test where i physically disconnect my network connection in the middle of the download. the loadingprocess stalls, but after aproximately 30 seconds Event.COMPLETE is thrown

Comment: The last paragraph is pretty much straight from the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:complete.  When you do this, does httpStatus or ioError get dispatched?  I am not sure if I have ever tried that.

Comment: yes I receive a httpStatus right before the Event.COMPLETE - but in both cases, whether it was downloaded fully or whether i disconnected the cable. ioError is only thrown if there is no internet connection available when download starts

Comment: Have you watched this with a network analyzer or live http headers?  I am curious whether content-length is being sent back since is is an optional header (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)